# Accessing ViewModel properties from Viewclass

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image]I want to call Content page class from Android .cs Class.

I use  `StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(LoginPage)));`

showing error message

> "System.ArgumentException: type Parameter name: Type is not derived
>   from a java type  "

Does anyone know the solution for this? Please help me in Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be you App.xaml.cs class

```
public App()
{
  MainPage = new NavigationPage ( new MainPage());
}
```

`MainActivity.cs` file

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
{
    private TextView setting;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {       
         base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
         global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
         LoadApplication(new App());
         SetContentView(Resource.Layout.HomeScreen);
         setting = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.settingText);

        //check setting button is null or have value
        setting.Click += delegate
        {
            Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
        };
    }
}
```

Use code above & debug to check if `setting` button have instance or is `null`.

Comment: When I am trying with this showing Unhandled Exception:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. occurred

Comment: What is your startup page? Is your startup page already started?

Comment: Yap,The startup is HomePage.This not start page ,this page calling in Homepage's some button click event.

Comment: @SimTO - If this is not helping show me you code of android project & App.cs file. I'll try to look into it.

Comment: Check my updated answer. & check setting button is `null` or not.

Comment: Did you try my updated code as I have posted above. is your setting button have value?

Comment: Yes,I try it.I think this is the case for cannot call ContentPage directly from "Android native " code in Xamarin.Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace typeof(LoginPage) with LoginPage.Class or LoginPage::Class.java (kotlin)

Comment: The problem is on xamarin forms